# Can I reset "Time Remaining" in openam session

Tags: java, openam

I am configuring SingleSignOn(SSO) using OpenAm server and opendj ldap. OpenAm is providing a Max Session time as 120 minutes. that means a user cannot access application for more than 2 hours. This is contradict to our application usage. we don't want to restrict user to access our application for only 2 hours. Thus we came a requirement to extend OpenAm max session time through Java API/Code.

I have followed the OpenAm java rest API but i couldn't find the way to do it.
If any one could join their helping hands by providing the way to extend OpenAm session through Java , that would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The service which controls the session related timeouts is the 'iPlanetAMSessionService', which has global, realm- and user-level settings (user-level settings require user-level attributes in the data store).

The service attributes can be changed using the service management API http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/apidocs/com/sun/identity/sm/package-frame.html

ssoadm cli tool or OpenAM console uses this API.